# SAS column name replacement scheme

Tags: sas, pass-through

I have a pass-through query using `proc sql` (excerpt below), in which some of the resulting names are modified since they aren't valid SAS names. `1A` is replaced by `_A`, `2A` is replaced by `_A0`, and some other changes are made. My questions are:

- Is there a document which explains the rules for name replacement e.g. `2A` becomes `_A0`?
- Is it possible for me to change the way SAS corrects the names? For example, can I make `1A` become `_1A` instead of `_A`?

.

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle as clc([omitted]);
CREATE table out.bk_ald as
SELECT *
FROM connection to bpm (

SELECT
  , "1A"
  , "1B"
  , "1C"
  , "1D"
  , "1E"
  , "2A"
  , "2B"
  , "2C"
...
```

Comment: Did you check if the LABELs in BK_ALD match the original column names in Oracle?

Comment: @Tom I didn't until just now, but yes, turns out the labels are the original oracle names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the algorithm and I am not sure if it is published.  But you could either rename the column yourself on the Oracle side.

```
select * from connection to oracle (select "1A" as "_1A", ...);
```

Or rename on the SAS side. SAS will store the original name as the variable's LABEL.  You could query the metadata and use that to rename the variables.

```
proc contents data=bk_ald noprint out=contents; run;
proc sql noprint ;
  select catx(name,'=',cats('_',label)) into :rename separated by ' '
  from contents 
  where upcase(name) ne upcase(label)
  ;
quit;
data want ;
  set bk_ald;
  rename &rename ;
run;
```

Comment: Does `option validvarname = any;` make any difference in this situation?

Comment: Using validname=any should mean that the variables are not renamed.  But you would need to use name literals to reference them. `"1A"n`.  If you did need to still issue rename statement like above then you should add in `NLITERAL()` function calls to the select statement so that it generates valid variable references.